# JavaFX Canvas is not drawing image

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, webcam

I am trying to take input from webcam and draw it in the canvas.

For this I wrote following block of code:

```
void addImageToCanvas(Image img){
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());  
 }
```

If I pass only one Image in that function by hand, it works.

If I pass two `Image`s then it only draws the last one.

But I am implementing thread and calling it continuously from the thread. The function is then comes to stand still on the line:

```
gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
```

The part of code from where the method is invoked:

```
public void run() {

        try {
            FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(cameraId);

            CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
            grabber.start();

            IplImage grabbedImage;
            BufferedImage bufImg;
            int counter = 0;
            while (primaryCameraChosen != null) {
                grabbedImage = grabber.grab();
                bufImg = grabbedImage.getBufferedImage();
                addImageToCanvas(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufImg, null));
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){}
            }
            grabber.stop();
            grabber.release();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
}
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong here? What is the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**So you have actually two problems**

> **1)** If I pass two Images then it only draws the last one.

You are drawing images to the same X, Y coordinates, with the same height and width. The result is (like in real life if your paint something on an existing painting) that only the last drawing is visible as it hides the first one. This is the expected working.

**Update after comment from OP:**

The problem with this line: `gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());` is, that at the first `Image` it tries to draw the `Image` using the actual height and width of the `Canvas`, but most probably at this moment the `Canvas` itself was not drawn, so the actual height and width are both zero, therefore the picture gets drawn with zero width and height.

Two possible solutions are:

**1)** Only start the `Thread` when the `Stage` that contains the `Canvas`  is actually showing. This will ensure that the `Canvas` has the correct height and width even at the first picture.

**2)** Listen to the width and height change of the canvas and redraw the `Image` if needed. This will ensure, that whenever the canvas is resized, the `Image` is redrawn (it has the advantage that the picture fits to the screen all the time so this one is the suggested way)

**The example contains both approaches.**

> **2)** But I am implementing thread and calling it continuously from the
>   thread. The function is then comes to stand still on the line

We shall see the full code what can be wrong, but until you update the post to include every part that is needed to detect the problem, here is an example which updates a canvas with an `Image` from a background thread every 3 seconds:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Canvas canvas;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            canvas = new Canvas();

            Pane pane = new Pane();
            pane.getChildren().add(canvas);
            canvas.widthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
            canvas.heightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());
            root.setCenter(pane);


            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                private ObjectProperty<Image> imageToBeDrawn = new SimpleObjectProperty<Image>(new Image(getClass().getResource("a.jpg").toExternalForm()));

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // Option 2: Listen to the width and height property change of the canvas and redraw the image
                    canvas.widthProperty().addListener(event -> addImageToCanvas(imageToBeDrawn.get()));
                    canvas.heightProperty().addListener(event -> addImageToCanvas(imageToBeDrawn.get()));

                    imageToBeDrawn.addListener(event -> addImageToCanvas(imageToBeDrawn.get()));

                    while(true){

                        Random rand = new Random();
                        if(rand.nextBoolean())
                            imageToBeDrawn.set(new Image(getClass().getResource("a.jpg").toExternalForm()));
                        else
                            imageToBeDrawn.set(new Image(getClass().getResource("b.jpg").toExternalForm()));

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.setDaemon(true);
            thread.start();

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            // Option 2: start the Thread only when the stage is showing
//          primaryStage.showingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
//
//              @Override
//              public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
//                  if(newValue)
//                      thread.start();
//                  
//              }
//          });

            primaryStage.show();



        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void addImageToCanvas(Image img){
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
            gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());  
        }});
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. You have misunderstood my first question. I had also run a thread then and waited for 10 seconds between images. It was only the last image that was drawn. Shouldn't it have drawn the first image then wait (for thread) and then draw the second one? And your code does not solve my problem, I have tried implementing it. Do you wish to see my full code? If yes, then my email id: bishwa420(at)gmail(dot)com . Cheers.

Comment: I have added more code for detecting bugs or errors.

Comment: I have updated the answer for you. I am almost sure that this causes the problem, both approaches shall work. The one with listeners is better as it ensures that the image gets always resized.

Comment: Actually I am doing it in Netbeans using FXML. I tried your first option but for futile. It now gives me exception:

    `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`


at line:

    `private ObjectProperty<Image> imageToBeDrawn = new SimpleObjectProperty<Image>(new Image(getClass().getResource("a.jpg").toExternalForm()));
`

Comment: That's because I have written an example with two pictures that you don't have of course,therefore you have to adapt it ... It can be simply `private ObjectProperty<Image> imageToBeDrawn = new SimpleObjectProperty<Image>();`, then in the run `bufImg = grabbedImage.getBufferedImage(); imageToBeDrawn.set(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufImg, null);`. The point is to update the property.

Comment: Yes brother, I tried that too. It doesn't update my canvas. One more question, does the canvas draws immediately as it receives, or it only receives the images and then draws them at once(which leads to replacing of the preceding images by the last one)? I guess latter is the case. Because I can draw now two images but with different co ordinates (and they are drawn at the same irrespective of their threading delay). Finally, is choosing canvas the right option to grab continuous footage from webcam and to show it on scene?

Comment: #1: if you follow the example it shall update the canvas as it is a working example:) #2: It draws as soon as the GUI thread has time to draw. If you try to draw a new image every 10 ms, there is a good chance that some of them (or most of them) will be skipped (because of the optimalization). #3 If you just place Images maybe a simple  [ImageView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the guideline. I shall do it and will definitely inform you about it.

Comment: The code in the answer here will try to draw to the canvas from a background thread, which violates JavaFX single thread model. The calls to `imageToBeDrawn.set(...)` need to be wrapped in `Platform.runLater(...)`.